# sudo apt update giving errors

Tags: package-management, updates, 22.04, update-manager

I'm getting this error while doing sudo apt-get update, I tried looking for similar question asked but those answer didn't helped.

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease
Ign:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:5 https://repo.waydro.id jammy InRelease
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/touchegg/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu jammy Release   404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu jammy Release   404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

on refreshing cache in Software & Updates I'm getting this error
[image: on refreshing cache in Software & Updates I'm getting this error]

Adding some more information
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why would you expect a PPA or *personal package archive* that was last maintained in 2020, have support for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or the 2022-April release?  Did you check that it provides support for your system?  ie. https://launchpad.net/~plushuang-tw/+archive/ubuntu/uget-stable from your question is where I looked, and 2020-Jan-09 being the last maintenance on the archive would have stopped me from adding it.  PPAs being 3rd party sources, rely on your checks to ensure they're safe for your system - did you do any?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to resolve the query. Unchecking them(not maintained) made the error go away.